# Tail probability bound on the expected value of measurable function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading Allan gut's graduate probability book and came across this problem,

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and $g$ be a non-negative, strictly increasing, differentiable function. Then,

$ Eg(X) < \infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g'(n)\textbf{P}(\textbf{X}>n) <\infty$  .

I am stuck and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is a non-random variable?

Comment: It is supposed to be non-negative. The exercise is found on page 76 of https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-4708-5.pdf

Comment: This looks wrong.  What if $g$ happens to be a function that satisfies $g(n)=n$ and $g'(n)=0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$? Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P[X>n]=0$ regardless of $X$.  But if $X$ is integer-valued then $X=g(X)$.

Comment: @Michael This cannot happen as $g$ is assumed to be strictly increasing so $g' > 0$.

Comment: Strictly increasing does not imply $g'>0$. Consider $h(x)=x^3$ and notice that $h'(0)=0$.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, my bad!

Comment: You can build such a function $g$ by pasting together shifted versions of the function $b(x) = 3x^2-2x^3$, which has the property that it is strictly increasing over $x \in [0,1]$ and satisfies $b(0)=0, b(1)=1$, $b'(0)=b'(1)=0$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3x%5E2-2x%5E3%2C+0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1

Comment: @Michael What if g is such that g'(n)>0 for all n?

Comment: That does not matter.  You can modify the counter-example to make $g'(n)= \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ in which case $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P[X>n] < \infty$, again regardless of $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is false. As indicated by my comments, we can define a function $g$  that is strictly increasing, differentiable, and satisfies $g(n)=n$ and $g'(n)=0$ for all $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ (see also this Math.SE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3318737/1074816)). Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P[X>n]=0$ regardless of $X$, but if $X$ is non-negative and integer-valued then $g(X)=X$.

I found a PDF of the book [here](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/5678_2018-9-18-12-55-51.pdf) (see page 76).

Theorem 12.3 is wrong but can be fixed as follows:
Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable.  Let $g:[0, \infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is nonnegative, continuous, differentiable with a continuous derivative for all $x>0$, and satisfies $g'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x>0$. Then

a) $E[g(X)] = g(0) + \int_0^{\infty} g'(t) P[X>t]~\mathrm dt$

b) For $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\},$ define
\begin{align}
L_n &= \inf_{t \in [n, n+1]}g'(t)\\
H_n &= \sup_{t \in [n, n+1]}g'(t)
\end{align}
In addition to the conditions of part (a), suppose that $L_n/H_n\rightarrow 1$.
Then
$$E[g(X)]<\infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P[X>n]<\infty.$$

---

The conditions for part (b) are satisfied by functions $g$ of the form $g(x) = x^c$ for any $c> 0$.

---

To prove part (b) I use the fact that if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{v_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are nonnegative sequences and $v_n\rightarrow 1,$ then $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nv_n < \infty.$$

---

Proof of part (b): First suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P[X>n]<\infty$.  Let $m$ be such that $L_n>0$ for all $n \geq m$. Then from part (a)
\begin{align}
E[g(X)] &= g(0) + \int_0^{\infty} g'(t)P[X>t]~\mathrm dt\\
&= g(0) + \int_0^m g'(t)P[X>t]~\mathrm dt + \int_m^{\infty} g'(t)P[X>t]~\mathrm dt\\
&\leq g(0) + \int_0^m g'(t)P[X>t]~\mathrm dt + \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} H_nP[X>n]\\
&\leq g(0) + \int_0^m g'(t)P[X>t]~\mathrm dt + \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{L_n}g'(n)P[X>n]\\
\end{align}

where we have used the fact $g'(n)/L_n\geq 1$. The final expression is finite since we can utilize the previous fact with $v_n=\frac{H_n}{L_n}$ and $a_n=g'(n)P[X>n]$. Thus $E[g(X)]<\infty$.  The other direction is similar.

Comment: can you elaborate or provide some hints on how you proved part b using the lemma/fact that you stated(I have proved that fact but am failing to prove part b)?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mikeath : I changed the condition of part (b) to the more general one, and I added a proof of one direction for part (b).

Comment: That works. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Another sufficient condition for part (b), instead of $L_n/H_n\rightarrow 1$, is that the conditions of part (a) hold and $g'(t)P[X>t]$ is monotonic in $t$ (either nondecreasing or nonincreasing in $t$). This is because the integral of the tail of a monotone function can be bounded above, and also below, by sums of its samples at integer values of $t$. Since $P[X>t]$ is already nonincreasing in $t$, monotonicity of $g'(t)P[X>t]$ holds whenever $g'(t)$ is also nonincreasing in $t$ (that is, when $g$ is concave).

Comment: +1 for this expository post, Michael. I have understood the whole derivation. Just to recapitulate: the extra assumptions different from Gut are $g$ is continuously differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and the subsequent assumption that $L_n/H_n\to 1$ (did I miss something?). Could you tell how these extra assumptions succeed to avoid those counterexamples? In other words, how did you get motivated to take these very extra assumptions? Would be grateful if you could provide some insight on this. Thanks.

Comment: @User1865345  : Thanks.  I noticed that the Gut sum formula looked like an exact integral formula, so I needed to be able to claim $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)dt$ (for that I assumed $f'(t)$ was continuous). Then I noticed that if the derivatives do not change much over the intevals $t \in [n, n+1]$, the integral can be approximated by a sum (and I cannot play my $g'(n)=0$ trick to get a counter-example).

Comment: Let me summarise what I comprehended reading your answers, comments and pre-kidney's post: rapidly changing derivatives would impact the summation in a disproportionate way and can't be used to approximate $g(\cdot) $ and hence the integral even in small interval. To tame the erratic behavior, you imposed $L_n/H_n\to 1$ which would ensure that $g'(n) \ne 0$ for sufficiently large $n$s (a finite number of terms won't change the convergence) and also this would mean $g'(x) $ won't change erratically as $L_n/H_n\to 1.$ A very ingenious assumption.